# Unpacking SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - Wrong drive

Tags: sql, installation

I've just downloaded the SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe. After starting the EXE file, a dialog appears and shows that there are files extracting. Strangely, the installer unpacks the data is not to C:\ but on F:. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It extracts to the drive that has most free space !

Comment: Is it possible to chance this behavior? Is it the same as to manually unpack the archive with WinRAR?